# How to append a class-path entry to the Manifest?

Tags: java, gradle, classpath

My gradle build creates a manifest files including all the `*.jar` files contained in `lib/`. I'd like to add the `lib` directory to this classpath, so that `lib/log4j.properties` is grabbed at runtime by `myapp`. How can I *append* to `'Class-Path'` below?

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'myapp', 'Implementation-Version': version,
        'Class-Path': configurations.runtime.files.collect { it.name }.join(' lib/'),
    'Main-Class': 'ca.company.product.myapp.Application',
    'Built-By': System.getProperty('user.name'),
    'Built-JDK': System.getProperty('java.version')
    }
}
```

I've looked in gradle doc, not dug yet into Gravy. I've probably overlooked some questions on SO or Gradle forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out that variables can be concatenated as in regular Java. So following `build.gradle` worked for me:

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'myapp', 'Implementation-Version': version,
        'Class-Path': configurations.runtime.files.collect { it.name }.join(' lib/') + ' lib/log4j.properties',
    'Main-Class': 'ca.company.product.myapp.Application',
    'Built-By': System.getProperty('user.name'),
    'Built-JDK': System.getProperty('java.version')
}
```